# Sysprep WITHOUT creating new user

Tags: windows-7, deployment, sysprep

I have install a ghost server and i would like to deploy many Windows 7 64 bits.
Before creating the master i must sysprep it but i would like to know how to sysprering without create a new user after restart of the computer.

thanks !

Comment: Why would you need to create a new user?  This is the reason accounts like Administrator exist.

Comment: The administrator account is deactivate and and a user named "utilisateur" have the administrator right. So i don't want to create a new user

Comment: So log into the user that already exists.

Comment: can't, after syspreping computer start like the first time and add tu select your language, time zone, username etc...

Answer (score 3):

When at the OOBE setup, pres <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to enter audit mode.  You're actually logged into the admin account.  From there you can make changes to the system before deployment.  You'll likely want to look into building an answerfile for unattended setup and to ensure drivers persist past generalization.

See this resource for more info: [**Preparing an Image Using Sysprep and ImageX**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preparing-an-image-using-sysprep-and-imagex.aspx)

Comment: Anyway to add directly a file like unattend.xml who say "after syspreping don't create user just boot normally" ?

Comment: What do you want to happen at "boot normally" - a user, at some point, must be created - unless your machines join to a domain...?

Answer (score 3):

Create an answer file, and set the following two options to **True**:

```
SkipMachineOOBE
SkipUserOOBE
```

You will find these options in phase 7: oobeSystem, under Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup.

#### Update

You need to edit your `Unattend.xml` file using AIK from Microsoft to add these two options.
Also, you can manually edit the file using notepad or another text editor.
Look for:

```xml
<settings pass="oobeSystem">
```

Then under that section look for:

```xml
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"    >
```

Under that section add:

```xml
<OOBE>
    <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
    <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
    <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
    <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
    <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
</OOBE>
```

Comment: really thanks ! i don't use any software to configure sysprep except sysprep itself.can we do a unattend.xml directly with just this information ?

Comment: you need to edit your unattend.xml file using AIK tool from Microsoft; to add thus two options

Comment: Ok thanks but i must use AIK anyway to add manually the .xml file with only OOBE settings and not configure other parameter ?

Comment: When you open the xml file with AIK tool, it will show you all configured parameters, and allow you to add, delete, change other settings

Comment: ok but how create the xml file ?

Comment: Here is a quick tutorial http://theitbros.com/sysprep-a-windows-7-machine-%E2%80%93-start-to-finish/

Comment: @ITProStuff Just a minor correction, but the AIK is not required for building the unattend file.  It's simply XML, if you know the tags to use you can (and I do) edit it with just a text editor.

Comment: **@ITProStuff** i saw this tutorial but i would to create it WITHOUT AIK.. 
**@Colyn1337** and i want to do like this but i have no idea what i must put in (except fort the OOBE part now)

Comment: I use this one windowsafg.no-ip.org to generate simple xml

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old posting ... but I'm surprised nobody pointed this out sooner. As this is still valid and useful, it should be noted that the two options in the unnattend answer file which should be set to "true" are:

Skip**Machine**OOBE and
Skip**User**OOBE

"ITProStuff" erroneously lists Skip**Machine**OOBE twice ... I'm sure it was simply a typo, but to help others looking for clarity and understanding.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 1):

Following @ITProStuff answer, here is a minimal unattend.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <OOBE>
        <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
        <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
      </OOBE>
    </component>
  </settings>
</unattend>
```

To use it, just add */unattend:[path_to_unattend.xml]* to your sysprep command line. Set *processorArchitecture* to *x86* if you make it for a 32bit Windows.

Comment: On at least windows 10 skipping Machine OOBE will not Change the SID which means the system will have issues when used on a Active Directory Domain.